# ACR1255U-J1 How to send a command

Tags: smartcard, smartcard-reader, contactless-smartcard

I have been trying to figure out for days on how to send a command to this smart card reader. According to the documentation at https://www.acs.com.hk/download-manual/7664/REF-ACR1255U-J1-1.13.pdf at page 104 i have to send `E0h 00h 00h 52h 00h` to the device to get the battery level. Please can someone give me an hint. Thank you